# Can't run the tomcat server in intellij idea

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I can't run the tomcat. The Output:

```
/Users/penguin's_Slair/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.83/bin/catalina.sh run
[2022-11-18 05:01:44,981] Artifact JavaEELearning:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Error: Password file not found: /Users/penguins_Slair/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/tomcat/7e84e0cb-02db-490e-ae65-817458eed209/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/penguins_Slair/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/tomcat/7e84e0cb-02db-490e-ae65-817458eed209/jmxremote.access
sun.management.AgentConfigurationError
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.checkPasswordFile(ConnectorBootstrap.java:563)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:426)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
Disconnected from server
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ZgI.png)

I tried to reinstall tomcat, created new project and added tomcat server. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because the home directory has the " ' " symbol. But intellij idea can't find in penguins_slair because it is in penguin's_slair folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33471544)